# Hovering doesn't highlight some links

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, design

Hovering over links, not all of them are changing colour.

[image]

[image]

Comment: This only affects `:visited` links.

Comment: Comparing to other SE sites, I think the actual problem is that visited links have the same color as non-visited. On other sites, visited links have darker color, which does *not* change on hovering.

Comment: Oh, I see. I couldn't figure this out. Good to know! In the Hot Network Questions, visited links have a different colour even before hovering.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for reporting this issue.

I've changed color for :visited links (it will be slightly lighter - this is pattern we usually use on SE sites) but I haven't added :hover effect for :visited links. It might be bug (or feature request) but it's the same across whole network at the moment (I'm not saying it's ok) so updating it might be kinda tricky and time-consuming for now. Anyway, different color for :visited is in repo and is waiting for deploy.. Should be visible in ~24h.